# Wrap list of URIs with html tags with RegEx

Tags: php, regex, sed, awk

I have a list with URIs like this:

```
./journal.html
./john-voigt.html
./flower_power28182.html
```

Now I want to regex the file (chose one: sed/awk/php), so that the result looks like:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/journal.html">http://domain.com/journal.html</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/john-voigt.html">http://domain.com/john-voigt.html</a><br>
<a href="http://domain.com/flower_power28182.html">http://domain.com/flower_power28182.html</a><br>
```

Doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s/^\.(.*)$/<a href="http:\/\/domain.com$1">http:\/\/domain.com$1<\/a><br>/
```

For sed...

```
sed s_^\.\(.*\)$_<a\ href="http://domain.com\1">http://domain.com\1</a><br>_
```

Comment: Thanks, I mixed up the start and end symbols, edited to fix it.

Comment: sed 's/^\.(.*)$/<a href="http:\/\/domain.com\/$1">http:\/\/domain.com\/$1<\/a><br>/' input.txt > output.txt   ...doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @StephanKristyn I updated my answer to include the sed syntax, using the underscore character as the delimiter

Comment: The `<` and `>` shouldn't need to be escaped. In fact, you escaped two, but not the other four.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thanks, I tried a few ways at first and when it didn't work, I just edited until it did. They have been un-escaped.

Comment: Thanks, SED worked splendidly! With perl something might be wrong with my install, I tried: perl -p -i.bak -e 's/^\.$/<a href="http:\/\/domain.com\/$1">http:\/\/domain.com\/$1<\/a><br>/' list.txt and nothing happens.

Comment: @stephankristyn you forgot the part in parens. They are a back reference that lets you specify the $1 in the replace.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do :

```
$Array = array( './journal.html',
                './john-voigt.html',
                './flower_power28182.html');

foreach($Array as $Key => $Link){
    $Link = str_replace('./', '', $Link);
    $Array[$Key] = '<a href="http://domain.com/'.$Link.'">http://domain.com/'.$Link.'</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AWK:

```
awk 'BEGIN {url = "http://domain.com"} {sub(/\./, url); print "<a href=\"" $0 "\">" $0 "</a><br>"}'
```